# SQL query for joining a column with same name and value by different column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to join multiple tables and multiple values in one column under one assoc array, to dynamically output to screen, but it repeats query table multiple times for example, if I have 11 entries I get 3x more 33 entries.

The target is to unite 3 tables product + product_description + product_special by product_id.

The problem is in the field named "name" in which values often are similar and are distinguished only by the next column, in which it is stated that this product name is for language 1 or 2, or 3.

I want to extract that with data from the product table model, price, etc.

##### My data

Table `product`:

```
| product_id | model  | price      |
| ---------- | ----- | ----------- |
| 1          | as123 | 1           |
| 2          | ab123 | 2           |
| 3          | az123 | 3           |
```

Table `product_description`:

```
| product_id | name  | language_id |
| ---------- | ----- | ----------- |
| 1          | apple | 1           |
| 1          | apfel | 2           |
| 1          | pomme | 3           |
```

Table `product_special`:

```
| product_id | price | end_date    |
| ---------- | ----- | ----------- |
| 1          | 9.99  | 2023-12-13  |
| 2          | 1.00  | 2023-12-12  |
| 3          | 99.00 | 2023-12-12  |
```

I tried joining, union, group and so on can't seem to understand how to unite the query so #### that results for one product be in one array not multiple.

I'm using PHP 7.4 and MySQL 5.7.39.

I'm quite new to SQL and development so please don't judge too harsh.

##### This is what I got so far:

```
    (array) [253 elements]
0: 
(array) [4 elements]
product_id: (string) "9"
model: (string) "HP EliteBook 840 G5 Silver"
name: (string) "Oneplus Nord CE 5G 8GB/128GB Blue EU"
language_id: (string) "3"
1: 
(array) [4 elements]
product_id: (string) "9"
model: (string) "HP EliteBook 840 G5 Silver"
name: (string) "Oneplus Nord CE 5G 8GB/128GB Blue EU"
language_id: (string) "2"
2: 
(array) [4 elements]
product_id: (string) "9"
model: (string) "HP EliteBook 840 G5 Silver"
name: (string) "Motorola Moto G71 5G DS 6GB/128GB Balck EU"
language_id: (string) "3"
```

Note:
because of the field named "name" which repeats the query result by x name times

##### From running this query command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    product.product_id,
    product.model,
    product_description.name, 
    product_description.language_id
FROM 
    product  
JOIN 
    product_description ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id
                        AND product_description.language_id = 1
                         OR product_description.language_id = 2
                         OR product_description.language_id = 3
ORDER BY 
    product.product_id;
```

##### The example I would like to get:

```
 0: 
 (array) [2 elements]
 name1: (string) "HP EliteBook 840 G5 Silver"
 name2: (string) "HP EliteBook 840 G5 Silver"
 name3: (string) "HP EliteBook 840 G5 Silver"
 product_id: (string) "9"
 1: 
 (array) [2 elements]
 name1: (string) "Lenovo ThinkPad P52s 20LB000HPB" 
 name2: (string) "Lenovo ThinkPad P52s 20LB000HPB"
 name3: (string) "Lenovo ThinkPad P52s 20LB000HPB"
 product_id: (string) "11"
```

Edit: The problem for me is that results are repeated 3 times(for each language).
I want to join them and then use something like where language id is 1 is named as language1, language id = 2 as language2(I m fetching assoc array per product) and that's why under one result, not times 3.
I tried ordering by id but in the language table, the primary key is different so I get an error that I cannot order join results by id because it's unaggregated.

Comment: You should be joining on product_id, product name is irrelevant except for display purposes.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm not 100% sure what he's trying to do, but it seems to me that it is probably a php problem and not a sql problem.  He seems to want to achieve some kind of formatting outcome, but I think he's getting hung up on the arrays and how to join.  It's a little hard to follow.  He says he's new, so I think he's just having trouble formulating the question.

Comment: I created a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/CM-YF3Sp) and it's completely unclear what the REAL problem is.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland -- he has a expected output there so I think it is clear what he wants... 3 name columns

Comment: @hogan: sometimes people say they want to do something, but they're not really explaining their real goal, just what they think they need to do to accomplish it.  His objective is to "dynamically output to screen", which I think is arguably a php problem, especially if you are going to end up using multiple self joins to get it in SQL.  I don't think he has explained clearly what he wants yet.  The part about the associative arrays is probably just confusing things.  If you are right and your solution addresses his actual problem, then he will accept your answer.

Comment: @user20110887 It might be helpful if you indicated what you want to output to the screen, instead of what associative array you want to have, since your goal is the screen output and the associative array is an intermediate step.  Using your sample data, can you say what your desired display output would be for product_id 1, model as123?

Answer (score 0):

You want all 3 names?  You have to join 3 times once for each

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id,
    p.model,
    name1.name as name1, 
    name2.name as name2, 
    name3.name as name3
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN product_description name1 ON p.product_id = name1.product_id AND name1.language_id = 1
LEFT JOIN product_description name2 ON p.product_id = name2.product_id AND name2.language_id = 2
LEFT JOIN product_description name3 ON p.product_id = name3.product_id AND name3.language_id = 3
ORDER BY p.product_id;
```

Comment: `Unknown column 'product.product_id' in 'field list'`, see last query in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/oan6jSmi)

Comment: @Luuk -- updated fiddle with fixed version above -- works as expected

Comment: ok, see: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7zODeaS1)

Comment: I posted the link so anyone can see the results of you query (for this who are not skooled in SQL)